# ElectronJS - Cannot get property 'join' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

I'm trying to create an application that runs from the tray.

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

How do I fix this?

My main.js is as follows:

```
const { app, Menu, BrowserWindow, Tray, systemPreferences } = require('electron');
const { path } = require('path');

let tray = null;

try {
  require('electron-reloader')(module)
} catch (_) { }

app.on('ready', () => {
  tray = new Tray(getIcon());
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    tray.on('click', tray.popUpContextMenu);
  }
  setMenu();
  tray.setToolTip('Student Eye');
});

const getIcon = () => {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    return path.join(__dirname, './icon_light.png');
  }
  return path.join(__dirname, './icon_dark.png');
}

const openStatusWindow = () => {
  const window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, height: 600, icon: 'icon_default.png', webPreferences: {
      enableremotemodule: true,
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  window.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
}

const setMenu = () => {
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'Status',
      click() { openStatusWindow(); }
    },
    {
      label: 'Quit',
      click() { app.quit(); }
    }
  ]);
  tray.setContextMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const path = require('path');
```

NOT

```
const { path } = require('path');
```

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: Thanks this has fixed it